# Replace a win32 call and set lastError

Tags: frida

I'm using Frida to replace some win32 calls such as CreateFileW. I need to replace because I need to fundamentally change how the call works for various reasons. I'm finding that if I try to do something which indicates failure by setting a thread-local error (e.g. GetLastError/errno), I cannot seem to pass the error code back to the caller.

For example, the following code results in the output which follows.

```
import atexit
import os
import time
import signal
import sys

import frida


from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Callable, cast, Union

from frida_tools.tracer import main

pid = frida.spawn(program="C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe", argv=["notepad.exe", "badfile"])

def do_attach_no_catch(pid):
    session = frida.attach(pid)
    script = session.create_script("""

const createFileWPtr = Module.getExportByName(null, 'CreateFileW');
const createFileWInput = ['pointer', 'int', 'int', 'pointer', 'int', 'int', 'pointer']
const createFileW = new SystemFunction(createFileWPtr, 'uint64', createFileWInput)
Interceptor.replace(createFileWPtr, new NativeCallback((fileName, access, shareMode, secAttr, createDisp, flags, templateFile) => {
    send("Running createW")
    const asStr = fileName.readUtf16String();
    send(`Got ${asStr}`);
    const result = createFileW(fileName, access, shareMode, secAttr, createDisp, flags, templateFile);
    send(result)
    this.lastError = result.lastError
    return result.value
}, 'uint64', createFileWInput))
Interceptor.flush();
    """)
    def on_message(message, data):
        print(message)

    script.on('message', on_message)
    script.load()
    session.resume()

def do_attach(pid):
    do_attach_no_catch(pid)

print("Starting")
do_attach(pid)
frida.resume(pid)
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Running createW'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Got C:\\Windows\\Globalization\\Sorting\\sortdefault.nls'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': {'value': '800', 'lastError': 0}}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Running createW'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Got C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\staticcache.dat'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': {'value': '836', 'lastError': 0}}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Running createW'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Got C:\\Windows\\Registration\\R000000000006.clb'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': {'value': '1000', 'lastError': 0}}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Running createW'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Got C:\\Windows\\System32\\OLEACCRC.DLL'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': {'value': '1016', 'lastError': 0}}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Running createW'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Got badfile.txt'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': {'value': '18446744073709551615', 'lastError': 2}}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Running createW'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': 'Got C:\\Windows\\System32\\imageres.dll'}
{'type': 'send', 'payload': {'value': '1180', 'lastError': 0}}
```

It's worth noting that notepad, at the end, pops up an error dialog saying no error happened -- i.e. it received an error code of 0. The documentation of the javascript api implies that setting `this.lastError` should do the trick. The docs mention that it exists in `attach`, and that replace is provided with a `this` object whose properties are similar to attach's.

I'm wondering if I'm just missing some simple integration which allows me to pass back the error code from the underlying function call, or whether this is fundamentally impossible with Frida as it stands.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this issue? I am facing a similar problem. Specifically, I replaced a function in my binary that wrapped GetLastError with another function from a DLL. However, I have noticed that instead of returning the actual error, GetLastError now returns a value of 0.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find anything great. For my case I worked around it where I could by just rewriting the arguments in onEnter so they went somewhere else that I could "proxy" to the new behaviour. It's not really what I wanted though.